# How can I use the linkedIn JSAPI within a Facebook app hosted on Heroku?

Tags: facebook, heroku, linkedin-api

Is it possible to access the linkedIn API through a facebook app? Facebook/Heroku blocks my code when it tries to access http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js, so I copied the JS and cloned it into my heroku app. But now, the app does not throw an error and nor does it connect to my linkedIn account and display my linkedIn headline as it is supposed to.

Is this a security/permissions matter or am I doing something wrong here? I went to my linkedIn apps page and added my heroku site as one of the domains that will access the API, but I don't think a call is even reaching linkedIn from heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it blocked **http**://platform.linkedin.com/in.js is because you were accessing it through http. If you refer in.js as **https**://platform.linkedin.com/in.js, it wont be blocked. If the issue is related to the *domains that will access the API* not being specified in App configuration of Linkedin then it will be clearly shown in Chrome browser console.